# Update user password methods breaks in external Read Write LDAP mode of WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using a external ApacheDS LDAP with WSO2 IS. I can update user password via Management Console very well. It works fine. Then I tried to use UserAdmin service to do this. I used the changePasswordByUser method in that. I have consumed the service using SOAPUI. I can send the first update request fine. I looked at the LDAP and the update is succeeded. I can log in to Management Console using the updated password.

When I tried to update it for the second time onwards using the updated password, its sends this response,

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Can not access the directory service</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <ns:UserAdminUserAdminException xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd">
                    <UserAdminException xsi:type="ax2627:UserAdminException" xmlns="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd"
                                        xmlns:ax2627="http://common.mgt.user.carbon.wso2.org/xsd"
                                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                        <ax2627:message>Can not access the directory service</ax2627:message>
                    </UserAdminException>
                </ns:UserAdminUserAdminException>
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Audit logs says,

```
[2014-05-29 16:32:53,078]  INFO -  'demoTest@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2014-05-29 16:32:53,077+0000] 
[2014-05-29 16:32:53,204]  INFO -  Initiator : demoTest@carbon.super | Action : Change Password by User | Target : demoTest@carbon.super | Data : {  } | Result : Failed
```

No other exception in the logs :( Can anyone help me to get this solved?

Comment: Found the problem! The LDAP is not allowing the password to be set back to values which are used in reason history. Need to disable that. That's why admin service has failed.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem! The LDAP is not allowing the password to be set back to values which are used in reason history. Need to disable that. That's why admin service has failed. You can use ads-pwdInHistory property in ApacheDS to do this.